# virtual box on mac for ie testing, how to look at local host?

Tags: internet-explorer, localhost, virtualization, virtualbox

I have downloaded and installed virtual box and the extension for ie7/8/9.

How can I browse 'localhost' files.

I run a web server locally for ruby on rails at localhost:5000.

As you can see below, I can access my server locally ok but virtual box doesn't see it using the same address.  How can I get virtual box to see my local web server addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you can ping the ip of local box from virtual machine. Once you can ping, 
http://:5000/ will work.

If the machine is unix/linux you can type ifconfig in terminal to get your ip.

In windows it is ipconfig to get the ip address of windows virtual box.